# Can't get SSS to work with Principled BSDF shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

I can't seem to get the SSS to work with the new principled BSDF shader of Blender 2.79. The SSS effect is almost invisible.
Please see the image below:[image: SSS with Principled BSDF comparison]

Does anyone know how to use this shader for SSS?

Here is the Blender scene in case someone wants to examine it: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47835

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an expert, but I think increasing Subsurface Radius to 10 does the job?

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much!! I was thinking increasing the subsurf value would help (got confused because of the traditional subsurf material) but it was giving some weird result. But increasing the value of subsurf radius gives the correct result!
https://imgur.com/a/cW7cA

Answer (score 1):

The only difference that you have, is that  on traditional SSS you are setting radius to 10, and you are missing that step in Principled BSDF. You may try to add a "value" node (can be color ramp, or whatever you want, but for this simple purpose the "value" node is enough) and set it to 10, and connect it to "subsurface radius" option on principled node.

Comment: This should also work by clicking on the 'Subsurface Radius' box in the Principled Shader. The radius inputs for rgb will expand. Click and drag from first to last input and enter '10' in all of them at once.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I was thinking increasing the subsurf value would help (got confused because of the traditional subsurf material) but it was giving some weird result. But increasing the value of subsurf radius works perfectly!